# Check if a branch is empty

Tags: github-api

Is there a way to check if a branch is empty using the github API?

[/repos/:owner/:repo/branches/:branch](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get-branch) returns the last commit, but how do I check if the commit belongs to the same branch or the parent branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As illustrated in "[Find the parent branch of a git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161204/6309)", a git branch has no "parent branch".

A branch can be empty compared to another, and ahead compared to another:

```
--x--x (branch1)
      \
       o--o (branch2, branch3)
```

Here, `branch3` could be considered "empty" when compared to `branch2`, and 2 commits ahead when compared to `branch1`.

And there is no way to know if `branch3` was created from `branch2` or `branch1`.

With the GitHub API, you would need to [compare two commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits), which can be two branch names:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/compare/hubot:branchname...octocat:branchname
```

That would give you fields of interest like:

```
"status": "behind",
"ahead_by": 1,
"behind_by": 2,
```

But that status is only relative to "another branch", without easy way to know if that "other branch" is its "parent" or not.

Comment: what about `total_commits` returned by the comparison? Same problem?

Comment: @Johnny yes, same issue.