# How can I get number of commits from Github API until certain branch

Tags: git, github, github-api

I want to get how many commits has done until a certain branch created from the Github API.

For example in git cli I'm doing: `git log --no-merges --oneline ${branchHash} | wc -l` and I can see the number.

From the Github API there's a limit of 100 so if I have more than 100 commits I can't get them all.

Is there any solution for that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little thing to solve this:

[Gist "Easy way to calculate commits count from the GitHub API](https://gist.github.com/yershalom/a7c08f9441d1aadb13777bce4c7cdc3b)".

It is based on using the [`compare` URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962188/6309) of the [GitHub Commit API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits#compare-two-commits), and using the `total_commits` field:

```
compare_url = '{}/repos/{}/{}/compare/{}...{}'.format(base_url, owner, repo, first_commit, sha)

commit_count = commit_req.json()['total_commits'] + 1
```

Comment: +1. Links-only answers are discouraged (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/6309), so I took the libery to add some references, links and details: please edit it some more if you think I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid doing multiple queries, you could use a [GraphQL one](https://developer.github.com/v4/), similar to [this one](https://platform.github.community/t/how-to-fetch-commits-from-repos/643/2) or [this one](https://gist.github.com/jonathansick/8bbe88a85addaeeea4e7fe9ef15b016b): it will fetch all the commits for a given branch, allowing you to count them.

```
{
  repository(name: "sickvim", owner: "jonathansick") {
    ref(qualifiedName: "master") {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          id
          history(first: 5) {
            pageInfo {
              hasNextPage
            }
            edges {
              node {
                oid
              }...
```

Comment: Thanks mate,
But I tried something like this and got the next answer:
```{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Requesting 101 records on the connection exceeds the `first` limit of 100 records."
    }
  ]
}```

Comment: Hi,
Used this:
```{
  repository(name: "sickvim", owner: "jonathansick") {
    ref(qualifiedName: "master") {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          id
          history(first: 101) {
            pageInfo {
              hasNextPage
            }
            edges {
              node {
                messageHeadline
                oid
                message
                author {
                  name
                  email
                  date
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```