# Master merge commit

Tags: git, github

I am working on some technical verification.

Suppose, I am working on feature branch. I have created a pull request from the feature branch to the master branch and already have a series of commit.

I have started working on my git-bash and let's say I have added a commit `M` but have not pushed it to my feature branch.

After that, I have used the merge command to merge and close my pull request.

The interesting thing is: my pull request will not show any account of commit `M`, but on my `master` branch, this commit `M` will be pushed.

How do I verify if the number of commit in the pull request is same as in the master branch, using the GitHub API?

[image: I added the feature one commit to my pull request]

The above image show that I have added the feature one commit to my pull request.

[image: used the merge command, to merge my feature-branc]

The above image shows that when I have used the merge command, to merge my feature-branch, I have added two commits on my `master` branch.

Git log

[image: Git log]

Comment: At some point you pushed commit M else it would not be on Github. Would you show `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` please? This will show the true history.

Comment: Updated in the question.
Like, I Need to work with the github api to figure out the change.

Comment: If you merge a PR on Github it should generate a merge commit, but your history has no merge commits. You said "*I have used the merge command to merge and close my pull request.*" What, exactly, do you mean? Did you do a `git merge` locally? Or did you push a button on Github? Or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but on my master branch, this commit M will be pushed.

It should not be pushed, unless you have locally created `M` on `master`, instead of your local feature branch.

From your logs, you have merged `feature2` on `master` locally, and then push, which is not indeed the normal workflow.
(Normally, you push the updated `feature2`, which update your PR in progress)

You can use, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47855527/6309), the [compare URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962188/6309) of the [compare commits API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/commits#compare-two-commits), to compare `feature2` and `origin/feature2`, and check for differences.